# Проектирование Искуственного Интелекта

Tags: c++, искусственный-интеллект

В данный момент пишу шахматы на C++ Qt. Графическую оболочку реализовал. Встал вопрос по поводу как лучше всего реализовать искусственный интеллект. Я его представляю как перебор всех возможных вариантов хода. Нашел информацию что необходимо просчитывать варианты ходов через Нейронные сети. Дайте пожалуйста ориентир и если возможно материал где изложена похожая проблема.

Comment: Я бы начал плясать от статьи в Википедии про Deep Blue с упором не на исторические факты, а на теорию шахмат, тоже затронутую в этой статье. Вообще материалов по этой теме, мягко говоря, много.

Comment: @Danatela я читал ряд статей по проектированию искуственного интелекта в общих чертах. где приводится довольно таки тривиальная проблема. по поводу Deep Blue спасибо, прочитаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компьютерные игрушки-шахматы уж точно были уже в 80-е... Поэтому, думаю врядли там используются нейронные сети, обычный перебор...

Допустим мы играем за белых, компьютер за чёрных. Алгоритм будет такой...

1. Просчитываем возможные ходы чёрных (всего-то максимум 16 фигур)
2. Просчитываем возможные ходы белых
3. Делаем так несколько итераций

Количеством итераций определяется "ум мозга компьютера".

Делаем несколько итераций, вычисляем сколько фигур осталось у белых в очках. Чем меньше очков, тем лучше...

ХОДИМ!

Comment: спасибо, вы очень помогли, направили мои размышления в правильное русло.

Comment: Если что, могу поучаствовать в проекте - стало интересно! Пишите в контакты...

Comment: Извините но это практическая работа для кафедры, так что лучше я ее буду сам вымучивать, но спасибо за то что отозвались !

Answer (score 2):

посмотрите gnu chess (с открытым исходным кодом). А вообще интерфейс это одна стомиллиардная в шахматах